# Generate data rows from data.frame in R

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I have file in R that looks like this:

```
Sample top bot value
A1       0  10   20
A2      10  20   23
A3      20  25   12
A4      25  30   23
```

I need to inflate this to increments of top and bottom and divide the value among those

```
Sample top bot value
A1       0   1  2
A1       1   2  2
A1       2   3  2
A1       3   4  2
A1       4   5  2
A1       5   6  2
...
```

I guess I have to create a for loop, but no idea how to generate the new data.frame.
Its tricky to find something about that, since most questions aim to crunch down data, instead of blowing it up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `lapply` to apply a function to subsets of a data frame:

```
# Your data frame:
dat <- read.table(text = "Sample top bot value
A1       0  10   20
A2      10  20   23
A3      20  25   12
A4      25  30   23", header = TRUE)


do.call(rbind, lapply(seq(nrow(dat)), function(x) {
  tmp <- seq(dat$top[x], dat$bot[x])
  top <- head(tmp, -1)
  bot <- tmp[-1]
  value <- dat$value[x] / length(top)
  data.frame(Sample = dat$Sample[x], top, bot, value)
}))
```

This returns:

```
   Sample top bot value
1      A1   0   1   2.0
2      A1   1   2   2.0
3      A1   2   3   2.0
4      A1   3   4   2.0
5      A1   4   5   2.0
6      A1   5   6   2.0
7      A1   6   7   2.0
8      A1   7   8   2.0
9      A1   8   9   2.0
10     A1   9  10   2.0
11     A2  10  11   2.3
12     A2  11  12   2.3
13     A2  12  13   2.3
14     A2  13  14   2.3
15     A2  14  15   2.3
16     A2  15  16   2.3
17     A2  16  17   2.3
18     A2  17  18   2.3
19     A2  18  19   2.3
20     A2  19  20   2.3
21     A3  20  21   2.4
22     A3  21  22   2.4
23     A3  22  23   2.4
24     A3  23  24   2.4
25     A3  24  25   2.4
26     A4  25  26   4.6
27     A4  26  27   4.6
28     A4  27  28   4.6
29     A4  28  29   4.6
30     A4  29  30   4.6
```

Comment: It works well with this example, but in my original data I get

Error in seq.default(x$top, x$bot)) : 'from' must be of length 1

The original data is in floating numbers, though all ending on .0, could that be the problem?

Comment: @mace Do you have any `Sample` values with more than one row?

Comment: Thanks, this works. There are three exceptions though:
NA values, if top=bot and if the difference btw top and bot <0. I fixed the NAs in the data, the second can be avoided by setting value to zero and the third by using seq(, by=0.1).
Thanks